# Looping and compare database entries with python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql database where I get weighing machine results entries, which look like this:

```
0      2016-11-06 08:36:19
7300   2016-11-06 08:43:11
19200  2016-11-06 08:43:12
35980  2016-11-06 08:43:17
45600  2016-11-06 08:43:21
45820  2016-11-06 08:43:27
45840  2016-11-06 08:43:28
45860  2016-11-06 08:43:29
26940  2016-11-06 08:44:34
19760  2016-11-06 08:44:36
3440   2016-11-06 08:44:38
0      2016-11-06 08:44:44
1400   2016-11-06 08:46:00
7120   2016-11-06 08:46:04
11240  2016-11-06 08:46:06
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:10
11240  2016-11-06 08:46:11
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:12
3940   2016-11-06 08:46:51
0      2016-11-06 08:46:56
```

When something is on the weighing machine, the entries will start to update from 0 to the real weight of the object on the weight machine, but till they get to the real weight I get all the values going up. When the difference on 3-4 the entries is less than 50kg, we are at the real weight. Then the weight will drop to 0 again, and will start the same cicle when something is on it. From the above example, these are the entries I am interested in:

```
45840  2016-11-06 08:43:28
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:10
```

I was thinking to compare each entry with the following one, and when the difference is less than 50 kg for 3 entries, get one of the entries and continue like this for other ones, but I don't how exactly I can do this in Python.

This is what I have to start with:

```
import MySQLdb
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user = "bla", passwd = "0000", db = "tracking")
cursor = database.cursor()

query = "SELECT weight, added_date FROM balance_events WHERE added_date BETWEEN 'this will be a user input start date' AND 'this will be a user input end date' ORDER BY `added_date` DESC"
cursor.execute(query)

db= cursor.fetchall()
for i in db:
    print i[1] # I get all the weight values in that added_date interval.
```

How do I make my `for` loop in order to get the desired output? Also is there a way to check the timestamp on the added_date in order constrain the time of the weight event (0 to 0) to be more than 5 minutes, and to ignore the ones that have the duration under 5min?

Comment: dont' you have any control over how the data is stored?

Comment: I don't have, the aplication that insert the data in my db it's not on my side.